# What are these pipes for and how can I seal them off to cover them?

Tags: copper, old-pipes

[pipes coming up through floor in dormer (added in the 90's maybe)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssbwE.png) ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssbwE.png)enter image description here Renovating a house from circa 1900. There are these random copper pipes sticking out in two of the rooms from the ceiling/ floor of dormer. They do not appear to be connected to anything. Please see photos.

Can anybody tell me what they might be for and how i might seal them off to cover them? can they be cut down?

There used to be a gas fireplace in the blue room about 20 years ago- could the ones from the ceiling have been connected to that. If so how to i get rid of them?
[image: pipes coming through ceiling in lounge]

Comment: Without a pic we all would be guessing.  ( you may need to resize the photo downward.)

Comment: Without the picture, can you tell us if the pipes are open or capped/closed off?  Open pipes are usually okay to remove.

Comment: To attach photos, Edit your question, then click on the "mountain landscape" button at the top right of the edit box.

Comment: ok- added pictures! would appreciate any advice.

Comment: You should figure out where they're going anyway.  We can make very reasonable educated guesses but there could be some nonsensical arrangement under there.